# Oracle SQL statement not working

Tags: sql, oracle

Can someone please tell me exactly what is wrong with this SQL and why it is not executing!

```
DROP TABLE CAR5849;
CREATE TABLE CAR5849 (
  IDNO      VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY
, MAKE        VARCHAR(20)
, MILES      NUMBER(6)
, DATEOFPURCHASE      DATE
);


INSERT INTO CAR5849 (IDNO, MAKE, MILES, DATEOFPURCHASE) VALUES (PGJ058,'Red Mustang', 27070, TO_DATE(‘11/07/2011’, ‘DD/MM/YYYY’);
INSERT INTO CAR5849 (IDNO, MAKE, MILES, DATEOFPURCHASE) VALUES (PGJ058,'Yellow Mustang', 35725, TO_DATE(‘24/09/2015’, ‘DD/MM/YYYY’);
INSERT INTO CAR5849 (IDNO, MAKE, MILES, DATEOFPURCHASE) VALUES (PGJ058,'Black Mustang', 14589, TO_DATE(‘11/02/2010’, ‘DD/MM/YYYY’);
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You need straight quotes for the to_date's.

Comment: Can you check you NLS parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing single quotes around the first argument.  I would recommend three other changes:

- VARCHAR2 instead of VARCHAR
- `DATE` instead of `TO_DATE()`
- Remove the primary key from `IDNO`, because you appear to want to set the column to the same value in multiple rows.

So:

```
DROP TABLE CAR5849;

CREATE TABLE CAR5849 (
  IDNO      VARCHAR2(20),
  MAKE      VARCHAR2(20),
  MILES      NUMBER(6),
  DATEOFPURCHASE  DATE
);

INSERT INTO CAR5849 (IDNO, MAKE, MILES, DATEOFPURCHASE)
    VALUES ('PGJ058', 'Red Mustang', 27070, DATE '2011-07-11');
INSERT INTO CAR5849 (IDNO, MAKE, MILES, DATEOFPURCHASE)
    VALUES ('PGJ058', 'Yellow Mustang', 35725, DATE '2015-09-24');
INSERT INTO CAR5849 (IDNO, MAKE, MILES, DATEOFPURCHASE)
    VALUES ('PGJ058', 'Black Mustang', 14589, DATE '2010-02-11');
```

Comment: i just tried this and got the following error message: Error at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint violated

Comment: @Karl . . . You are defining `IDNO` to be a primary key and then putting the same value in multiple rows.  You can't do that.

Comment: oops that was a stupid mistake, i just made the values unique, the error is gone but its not displaying any tables?

Comment: nvm i fixed it, i seem to be making countless stupid mistakes

Comment: @Karl . . . They say an expert is someone who has already made all the mistakes.

Comment: thanks :) quick question: is there a way I can write a where statement to only show results with a certain date? ie only show dates with '2010-02-11'?

Comment: `where dateofpurchase = date '2010-02-11'`.

Answer (score 0):

Column IDNO is defined as primary key, so you cannot add duplicate entries for this column, all 3 insert statements have the same IDNO value, have unique value for IDNO or remove the primary key from IDNO

Comment: thanks, i just got rid of the primary key,that seemed to have resolved the errors, but its still not showing me any tables

Comment: in insert statement try changing from to_date to just date, also after values you have opened 2 "(" but closed only one of them, also have the value of IDNO as 'PGJ058' (with the quotes) as it is defined as varchar